# Why are logical assignment (&=) operators disallowed in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

With the following code:

```
var x:boolean = true;

x &= false;
```

Results in `error TS2447: The '&=' operator is not allowed for boolean types. Consider using '&&' instead.`

I've looked around but can't find a reason why, there's a PR to make the error what it is: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/712 but still can't find the underlying reason for it.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: The `&` is the bitwise "and" operator so you apply this to integers, not booleans.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks. Post an answer and I'll close the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typescript 4.0+ now supports logical assignment. Here is the online [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQg9nANlAvFARgxECGA7KAHyjwFdFljS8ATCAMwEs8IaBuAWAChvtgoAHgC5YWVFGAAnUhE48uAqADIlaejkQBnWVAD0u1AD4o6rRG6KVaMhTZ6DKYzcQXlqqNTpMW7e0Y+0DMys3LwQ-CAi8Ejiptpy3CBuaFIydvr+ceZcSVYk5IjpDsZZickBXsG+GY4mGtrcQA).

```js
type Bool = boolean | null | undefined;

let x: Bool = true;

x &&= false; // => false
x &&= null; // => null
x &&= undefined; // => undefined

let y: Bool = false;

y &&= true; // => false
y &&= null; // => false
y &&= undefined; // => false
```

Which is equivalent to

```js
type Bool = boolean | null | undefined;

let x: Bool = true;

x && x = false; // => false
x && x = null; // => null
x && x = undefined; // => undefined

let y: Bool = false;

y && y = true; // => false
y && y = null; // => false
y && y = undefined; // => false
```

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak on behalf of the designers of TypeScript but the [& (bitwise AND)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND) operator is intended to perform the a bitwise AND operation on two integers. Your variable is a boolean and these values are combined using [&& (logical AND)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

In TypeScript you could conceivably create an `&&=` operator but the `&&` operator uses short-circuit evaluation where evaluation stops as soon the result is known which means that the semantic of `x &&= y` becomes a bit clouded.

Comment: This makes sense given the strongly-typed nature of Typescript

Comment: With respect, this does not.  C# is also a strongly typed language - in certain areas, actually _much_ more strongly typed - yet C# has unary logic operators.  Based on my own run-ins with this issue, as well as the experience I have with the language, I think the real issue is that TypeScript _actually is not_ strongly-typed, and that makes unary boolean operators difficult to implement.  You'd have to write a new language - e.g. Dart - and cleanly break from the JavaScript heritage to get certain language features.

Comment: @AndrewGray I agree with most of what you say, but this wouldn't require a new language. It would be enough to make `x &&= y` transpile to `x = x && y`. The semantic rules could be inferred as easily as any operation in TS - allow it for a mix of `boolean` and `any`, otherwise error.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was doing

```
x |= y
```

instead of what I meant, which is

```
x ||= y
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually TypeScript language allows "bitwise AND with Assignment" but it is different for a **number** variable, and for **boolean** variable type.

Here is a sample for number:

```js
a = 5;
b = 0;
c = 3;
console.log("Before assignment 'a' is " + a);
a &= c;
console.log("After 'c' assignment 'a' is " + a);
a &= b;
console.log("After 'b' assignment 'a' is " + a);
```

And for **boolean** type

```js
a = true;
b = false;
c = true;
console.log("Before assignment 'a' is " + a);
a &&= c;
console.log("After 'c' assignment 'a' is " + a);
a &&= b;
console.log("After 'b' assignment 'a' is " + a);
```